# Problem Compiling C++ Files with Python Script

Tags: c++, python-3.x, automation, compilation

I'm working on a Python script which does the following:

1. Changes the names of two folders within the folder called `src`. Within these 2 folders there are `C++` files which need to be compiled. The names of these two folders and the associated `C++` files are: `addition_calc` with `add.cpp` and `multiplication_calc` with `multiply.cpp`.
2. Once the folders have had their names changed to `addition` and `multiplication` and the associated `C++` files compiled, they will all appear in a folder called `target`.

Starting project structure:

`main.py`

`src/`

```
addition_calc/
    add.cpp

multiplication_calc/
    multiply.cpp
```

On running the application:

`$ python3 main.py src target`

Output project structure (which additionally includes the starting project): Note: I've included the `C++` `exe` files as they are desired

`target/`

```
 metadata.json

 addition/

     add.cpp
     add

 multiplication/

     multiplication.cpp
     multiplication
```

The two `C++` files:

**add.cpp**

```
 #include<iostream>

 double add(double, double);

 int main() {

     double a, b;

     std::cout<<"Enter two numbers: "; std::cin>>a>>b;

     std::cout<<"The sum of these two numbers is: "<<add(a,b)<<std::endl;


     }

     double add(double a, double b) {

     return a + b;

     }
```

**multiply.cpp**

```
     #include <iostream>

     double multiply(double, double);

     int main() {

         double a, b;

         std::cout<<"Enter two numbers: "; std::cin>>a>>b;

         std::cout<<"Multiplication of those two numbers is "<<multiply(a,b)<<std::endl;

     }

     double multiply(double a, double b) {

          return a * b;

      }
```

The `python` script:

```
import json
import shutil
from subprocess import PIPE, run
import sys


CALC_DIR_PATTERN = "calc"
CALC_CODE_EXTENSION = ".cpp"
#Note: tested using Golang: CALC_COMPILE_COMMAND = ["go", "build"]
#CALC_COMPILE_COMMAND = ["g++", "add.cpp", "multiply.cpp", "-o", "main"]
#testing with one `C++` file:
CALC_COMPILE_COMMAND = ['g++', '-o', 'add.cpp', 'add']


def find_all_calc_paths(source):
    calc_paths = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for directory in dirs:
            if CALC_DIR_PATTERN in directory.lower():
                path = os.path.join(source, directory)
                calc_paths.append(path)

        break

    return calc_paths


def get_name_from_paths(paths, to_strip):
    new_names = []
    for path in paths:
        _, dir_name = os.path.split(path)
        new_dir_name = dir_name.replace(to_strip, "")
        new_names.append(new_dir_name)

    return new_names


def create_dir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)


def copy_and_overwrite(source, dest):
    if os.path.exists(dest):
        shutil.rmtree(dest)
    shutil.copytree(source, dest)


def make_json_metadata_file(path, calc_dirs):
    data = {
        "C++_Folder_Names": calc_dirs,
        "Number_Of_Folders": len(calc_dirs)
    }

    with open(path, "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)


def compile_calc_code(path):
    code_file_name = None
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(CALC_CODE_EXTENSION):
                code_file_name = file
                break

        break

    if code_file_name is None:
        return

    command = CALC_COMPILE_COMMAND + [code_file_name]
    run_command(command, path)


def run_command(command, path):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)

    result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    print("compile result", result)

    os.chdir(cwd)

def main(source, target):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    source_path = os.path.join(cwd, source)
    target_path = os.path.join(cwd, target)

    calc_paths = find_all_calc_paths(source_path)
    new_calc_dirs = get_name_from_paths(calc_paths, "_calc")

    create_dir(target_path)

    for src, dest in zip(calc_paths, new_calc_dirs):
        dest_path = os.path.join(target_path, dest)
        copy_and_overwrite(src, dest_path)
        compile_calc_code(dest_path)

    json_path = os.path.join(target_path, "metadata.json")
    make_json_metadata_file(json_path, new_calc_dirs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv
    if len(args) != 3:
        raise Exception("You must pass a source and target directory - only.")

    source, target = args[1:]
    main(source, target)
```

***Errors generated***

```
g++: error: multiply.cpp: No such file or directory
compile result CompletedProcess(args=['g++', 'add.cpp', 'multiply.cpp', '-o', 'main', 'add.cpp'], returncode=1, stdout='')
g++: error: add.cpp: No such file or directory
compile result CompletedProcess(args=['g++', 'add.cpp', 'multiply.cpp', '-o', 'main', 'multiply.cpp'], returncode=1, stdout='')
```

Note: contents of `json` file not included; all is fine with this.

`Compiler`: `g++ 9.4.0`.
`Python`: `3.8.10`.
`OS`: `Ubuntu 20.04`.

So clearly a problem with the compiling stage of this but I can't see how to resolve it. Cheers.

Comment: `'g++', 'add.cpp', 'multiply.cpp', '-o', 'main', 'add.cpp'` doesn't really make sense with the code presented. Did you mean `'g++', '-o', 'main', 'add.cpp'`, or rather as your desired output structure suggest `'g++', '-o', 'add', 'add.cpp'`? (and the same for the other binary?)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So I tried `['g++', '-o', 'add', 'add.cpp']` for the `CALC_COMPILE_COMMAND` which still gave me the same error bar the one for `multiplication.cpp` which wasn't incorporated this time

Comment: The whole command should be just `g++ -o add add.cpp` and `g++ -o multiplication multiplication.cpp`. You wrote all that Python code, so I'm not sure why are you struggling with this part of the task? The constant part - if you really want to keep that `CALC_COMPILE_COMMAND` - would be `['g++', '-o']` and to that you have to append output file name (which you can extract from the input file name) and the input file name.